# Line spacing when creating new line

Tags: text, text-formatting

I have a plot which has a legend where text occasionally needs two lines. While I'm able to adjust the space between labels using "Spacings" how can I change the line-spacing within a label to match. For example:

```
ListLinePlot[{RandomReal[10, 10], RandomReal[10, 10], RandomReal[10, 10]}, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[
Automatic, {"One Line Label", "Two-Line\nLabel", 
 "Third One Line Label"}, LegendFunction -> "Panel", 
Spacings -> 0.1], {Left, Top}]]
```

[image: Line Spacing]

The second label has a larger gap than the others, which I can't figure out how to reduce.

UPDATE

Ulrich Neumann suggested using the "LineSpacing" option in Style, which doesn't work, however making the label a Text did work properly.

```
ListLinePlot[{RandomReal[10, 10], RandomReal[10, 10],RandomReal[10, 10]},
PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[
Automatic, {"One Line Label", 
 Text[Style["Two-Line\nLabel", LineSpacing -> {0.8, 0}]], 
 "Third One Line Label"}, LegendFunction -> "Panel", 
Spacings -> 0.1], {Left, Top}]]
```

[image: Fixed Image]

Comment: Try `Style` with the option `LineSpacing` for thr two line label.

Comment: Have tried this, it doesn't seem to work with plotlegends. However, if I make the label: Text[Style["Two-Line\nLabel",LineSpacing->{1,0,0}]] then it does work.

Comment: That's what I proposed in my comment!

Comment: Sort of, it requires an additional bracing of Text[] as well.